# Xcode 4.2 map view initWithDictionary

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I just upgraded to the new Xcode 4.2 and am having problems with loading map annotations from my plist.  I need to have the plist on a URL to update regularly.

I had no problems with the older version of Xcode, but am now getting a ARC error and

> Receiver type 'MapAnnotations' for instance message does not declare a method with selector 'initWithDictionary'.

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thank you in advance.

MapAnnotations.m code

```
-(id)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dict {
self = [super init];
if (self!=nil) {
    coordinate.latitude = [[dict objectForKey:@"latitude"] doubleValue];
    coordinate.longitude = [[dict objectForKey:@"longitude"] doubleValue];
    self.title = [dict objectForKey:@"name"];
    self.subtitle = [dict objectForKey:@"subtitle"];
    self.pin = [dict objectForKey:@"pin"];
}
return self;
```

}

section in Mapview.M

```
NSString *plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Locations" ofType:@"plist"];
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.MyPlist.plist"]];

if (array) {
    NSDictionary* myDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:[array count]];
    for (NSDictionary* dict in array) {
        MapAnnotations* annotation = [[MapAnnotations alloc]iniWithDictionary:dict];
        [mapview addAnnotation:annotation];
    }
    NSLog(@"The count: %i", [myDict count]);
}

else {
    NSLog(@"Plist does not exist");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error:

> Receiver type 'MapAnnotations' for instance message does not declare a method with selector 'initWithDictionary'

means the `initWithDictionary` method hasn't been declared in `MapAnnotations.h`.  In the older Xcode, I think this only resulted in a warning.

In `MapAnnotations.h`, declare the method:

```
@interface MapAnnotations : NSObject<MKAnnotation>

//any ivars, properties, and other method declarations here

-(id)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dict;  // <-- add this

@end
```

By the way, I assume this line is just a typo in your question:

```
MapAnnotations* annotation = [[MapAnnotations alloc]iniWithDictionary:dict];
```

It should say `initWithDictionary` (not `iniWithDictionary`).

Comment: Thank you so much.  That was my problem.  I'm still wrapping my head around all of this code.  I appreciate it mucho!!